# Assertion failed : area > 1.19209

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm getting this weird error when I run my program that uses `Box2D` which is really unexpected because it's in a file which is nowhere related to my project(unbuilt folder not linked to my project). I obtained a copy for `Box2D` for `VS12` and built it for my project and setup-ed the project following a tutorial here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEClRFKyGkw&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW&index=53

Here's my code:

```
void Box::init(b2World* world, const glm::vec2& position, const glm::vec2& dimensions)
{
    m_dimensions = dimensions;
    b2BodyDef boxDef;
    boxDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    boxDef.position.Set(position.x, position.y);
    m_body = world->CreateBody(&boxDef);
    b2PolygonShape boxShape;
    boxShape.SetAsBox(position.x / 2.0f, position.y / 2.0f);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;

    m_fixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
```

Where I've called the `init()`:

```
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -9.8f);
    m_world = std::make_unique<b2World>(gravity);
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
    b2Body* groundBody = m_world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2PolygonShape groundShape;
    groundShape.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundShape, 0.0f);
    Box newBox;
    newBox.init(m_world.get(), glm::vec2(0.0f, 14.0f), glm::vec2(15.0f, 15.0f));
    m_boxes.push_back(newBox);
```

A window pop's up as this:
[image: Debug Error]

The error printed on my console:

> Assertion failed : area > 1.19209 2896e-07F,
>   path_to_unbuild_box2d\box2d_v2.3.0\box2d\box2d\collision\shapes\b2
>   polygonshape.cpp, line 422

Here's where the error occur (when I click `Retry`) `line 336 b2Fixture.h`:

```
inline void b2Fixture::GetMassData(b2MassData* massData) const
{
    m_shape->ComputeMass(massData, m_density);
}
```

**Problem 1 fixed**

```
boxShape.SetAsBox(dimensions.x / 2.0f, dimensions.y / 2.0f); ///Instead of position.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The line of code that's failing is](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp#L422) (as mentioned in the "Assertion failed" message):

```
b2Assert(area > b2_epsilon);
```

It means your polygon has a puny size (look at the assertion, the area is less than `1.192092896e-07F`, which is the value `0.0000001192092896`, which is tiny).

Likely `boxShape` has the invalid size. Set a breakpoint on the line:

```
boxShape.SetAsBox(position.x / 2.0f, position.y / 2.0f);
```

and inspect the value of `position`. Make sure you're setting the box's dimensions to a sane value. My bet is that you aren't.

Comment: the value of `position.x=0` and `position.y=14` is this invalid?

Comment: Think about it: you're trying to create a box with a width of 0 and a height of 14. Does a box with a width of 0 sound valid?

Comment: thanks that was a logic error I had to use `dimension`

Comment: and another problem is why did I got an error in the file that I've never included in my project but I have a copy of that folder linked to my project.

Comment: The Box2D code contains some assertions that get compiled, and those assertions include some debugging information (like the name of the file and the line number). It's a nifty feature of assertions so you can know *which* assertion failed.